# Error al ingresar un valor mayor a 10 en Java

Tags: java

Hice un programa en donde el usuario digita el nombre de un alumno y sus 3 calificaciones de los parciales.

La calificación no puede ser mayor a 10 y si lo es entonces le pide ingresar otra calificación de nuevo.

Sin embargo cuando ingreso números mayores de 10 ésta de todas formas la almacena en lugar de pedirme que cambie el numero.

Otro error es que cuando ingreso la opcion de Consulta de promedios esta me regresa al menu principal en lugar de darme los promedios.

```js
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ExamenCalificaciones{
   public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException
   {
      BufferedReader  br=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      String []nombre= new String [100];
      int op_menu;
      int []calificacion_1= new int[100];
      int []calificacion_2= new int[100];
      int []calificacion_3= new int[100];
      int []promedio= new int[100];
      int totales=1;
      int x=0;
      int y=0;
      int i=0;
      int ejecutar=0;
      int aux;
      int exitmenu=0;
      String auxnombre;
      int passed=0;
      int flunked=0;
      
    
      do{ 
      System.out.println("Menu de Captura de Calificaciones");
      System.out.println("Ingrese la opcion deseada \n 1.Captura \n 2.Consulta de promedios \n 3.Salir");
    op_menu=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      
      if(op_menu==1)
      {
      System.out.println("Capturas");
      System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del alumno:");
      x=x+1;
      nombre[x]=br.readLine();
      nombre[x]=nombre[x].toUpperCase();
      do
      {
      System.out.println("Ingresa la primera calificacion:");
      calificacion_1[x]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      if(calificacion_1[x]>11 || calificacion_1[x]<1)
      {
      System.out.println("Favor de Ingresar valores no mayor a 10");
      }
      }while(calificacion_1[x]>11 || calificacion_1[x]<1);
      
      do
      {
      System.out.println("Ingresa la segunda calificacion:");
      calificacion_2[x]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      if(calificacion_2[x]>11 || calificacion_2[x]<1);
      {
      System.out.println("Favor de Ingresar valores no mayor a 10");
      }
      }while(calificacion_2[x]>11 || calificacion_2[x]<1);
      
      do{
      System.out.println("Ingresa la tercera calificacion:");
      calificacion_3[x]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      if(calificacion_3[x]>11 || calificacion_3[x]<1)
      {
      System.out.println("Favor de Ingresar valores no mayor a 10");
      }
      }while(calificacion_3[x]>11|| calificacion_3[x]<1);
      promedio[x]=(calificacion_1[x]+calificacion_2[x]+calificacion_3[x])/3;
      if(promedio[x]>=6)
      {
      passed=passed+1;
      }
      if(promedio[x]<6)
      {
      flunked=flunked+1;
      }
      
      exitmenu=1;
      }
      
      if(op_menu==2)
      {
      System.out.println("Consultar Promedios");
      for(x=1; x<totales; x++)
      {
      for(y=1; y<totales; y++)
      {
      if(promedio[y]<promedio[y+1])
      {
      aux=promedio[y];
      promedio[y]=promedio[y+1];
      promedio[y+1]=aux;
      auxnombre=nombre[y];
      nombre[y]=nombre[y+1];
      nombre[y+1]=auxnombre;
      }
      }
      }
      exitmenu=1;
      System.out.print(totales);
      for(x=1; x<totales; x++)
      {
      System.out.println("Nombre del alumno o alumna: "+nombre[x]+" Promedio Final: "+promedio[x]);
      
      }
     }
     if(op_menu==3)
     {
     
     System.out.println("Salida del programa \n Estos son los resultados");
     System.out.println("No. de Reprobados: "+flunked);
     System.out.println("No. de Aprobados: "+passed);
     }
   
     }while(exitmenu==1);
     
     
      }/*cierre del if menu 2*/
      
      }/*cierre de if opcion_menu*/
```

Comment: Veo algunos fallos, te voy contando en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la línea donde pone `if(calificacion_2[x]>11 || calificacion_2[x]<1);` tienes un punto y coma al final que impide la ejecución del bloque `{}`.

Por otro lado, el bucle que usas para repetir el menú hasta que se decida salir pones `} while (exitmenu == 1);`, pero quizá querías poner que se repitiera mientras el estado `exitmenu` sea diferente de `1`: `} while (exitmenu != 1);`. Yo hubiera preferido usar un tipo de dato `booleano`. Usas una lógica inversa que podría crearte problemas en un futuro o confundir a un lector.

Los comentarios de las llaves del final no se corresponden con sus emparejamientos.

Estás desperdiciando el índice 0 de la matriz por sumarle 1 a la posición antes de guardar los datos en ella. Haciendo el incremento posterior y comenzando los bucles por el índice 0 arregla ese problema.

El cálculo `promedio[x] = (calificacion_1[x] + calificacion_2[x] + calificacion_3[x]) / 3;` se hace con aritmética de enteros, tenlo en cuenta.

Los condicionales que empiezan por `if (promedio[x] >= 6) {` con mutuamente excluyentes, por lo que el segundo puedes ponerlo en el `else` y no hacer dos comprobaciones.

Usas `x` para mantener el índice el siguiente alumno, pero luego lo reutilizas como variable en las iteraciones que calculan promedios en la opción 2, y luego no usas `totales` para nada aunque lo usas como límite en los bucles... ¿qué sentido tiene? He cambiado donde usas `x` por `totales` para darle sentido y, además, evitar que pierda la cuenta cuando hagas listados intercalados con agregar nuevos alumnos.

Este es el código resultante:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ExamenCalificaciones {
  public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String[] nombre = new String[100];
    String auxnombre;
    int[] calificacion_1 = new int[100];
    int[] calificacion_2 = new int[100];
    int[] calificacion_3 = new int[100];
    int[] promedio = new int[100];
    int op_menu, totales = 0;
    int x = 0, y = 0, i = 0;
    int ejecutar = 0, aux, passed = 0, flunked = 0;
    boolean repetirmenu = true;

    do {
      System.out.println("Menu de Captura de Calificaciones");
      System.out.println("Ingrese la opcion deseada");
      System.out.println("1. Captura");
      System.out.println("2. Consulta de promedios");
      System.out.println("3. Salir");
      op_menu = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      switch(op_menu) {
      case 1:
        System.out.println("Capturas");
        System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del alumno:");
        nombre[totales] = br.readLine().toUpperCase();
        do {
          System.out.println("Ingresa la primera calificacion:");
          calificacion_1[totales]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
          if (calificacion_1[totales] > 11 || calificacion_1[totales] < 1) {
            System.out.println("Favor de Ingresar valores no mayor a 10");
          }
        } while (calificacion_1[totales] > 11 || calificacion_1[totales] < 1);

        do {
          System.out.println("Ingresa la segunda calificacion:");
          calificacion_2[totales] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
          if(calificacion_2[totales] > 11 || calificacion_2[totales] < 1) {
            System.out.println("Favor de Ingresar valores no mayor a 10");
          }
        } while (calificacion_2[totales] > 11 || calificacion_2[totales] < 1);
        do {
          System.out.println("Ingresa la tercera calificacion:");
          calificacion_3[totales] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
          if(calificacion_3[totales] > 11 || calificacion_3[totales] < 1) {
            System.out.println("Favor de Ingresar valores no mayor a 10");
          }
        } while (calificacion_3[totales] > 11 || calificacion_3[totales] < 1);
        promedio[x] = (calificacion_1[totales] + calificacion_2[totales] + calificacion_3[totales]) / 3;
        if (promedio[totales] >= 6) {
          passed++;
        } else {
          flunked++;
        }
        totales++;
        break;
      case 2:
        System.out.println("Consultar Promedios");
        for(x = 0; x < totales; x++) {
          for(y = 0; y < totales; y++) {
            if (promedio[y] < promedio[y+1]) {
              aux = promedio[y];
              promedio[y] = promedio[y+1];
              promedio[y+1] = aux;
              auxnombre = nombre[y];
              nombre[y] = nombre[y+1];
              nombre[y+1] = auxnombre;
            }
          }
        }
        System.out.print(totales);
        for(x = 0; x < totales; x++) {
          System.out.println("Nombre del alumno o alumna: " + nombre[x] +
            " Promedio Final: " + promedio[x]);
        }
        break;
      case 3:
        System.out.println("Salida del programa");
        System.out.println("Estos son los resultados");
        System.out.println("No. de Reprobados: " + flunked);
        System.out.println("No. de Aprobados: " + passed);
        repetirmenu = false;
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println("Opción errónea");
      }
    } while (repetirmenu);
  }
}
```